# pandas rounding when converting the series to int

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

How can I round a number of decimals based on an assigned series?
My sample data is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(1,5,size=(10,1)), columns=['Results'])
df['groups'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df['decimal'] = [1, 0, 2, 3]
```

This produces a dataframe like:

```
   Results    groups  decimal  
0  2.851325      A        1
1  1.397018      B        0
2  3.522660      C        2
3  1.995171      D        3
```

Next: each result number needs to be rounded the number of decimals shown in `decimal`. What I tried below resulted in an error of `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`

```
df['new'] = df['Results'].round(df['decimal'])
```

I want the results like:

```
   Results     groups decimal new
0  2.851325      A        1   2.9
1  1.397018      B        0   1
2  3.522660      C        2   3.52
3  1.995171      D        3   1.995
```

Comment: Sorry I got the columns mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a dict-like object to `DataFrame.round` to set different precision levels for different columns. So you need to transpose a single column DataFrame (constructed from `Results` column) twice:

```py
df['Results'] = df[['Results']].T.round(df['decimal']).T
```

Another option is a list comprehension:

```py
df['Results'] = [round(num, rnd) for num, rnd in zip(df['Results'], df['decimal'])]
```

Output:

```py
   Results groups  decimal
0    2.500      A        1
1    2.000      B        0
2    2.190      C        2
3    1.243      D        3
```

Note that since it's a single column, it's decimal places is determined by the highest decimal; but if you look at the constructor of this DataFrame, you'll see that the precisions have indeed changed:

```py
>>> df[['Results']].to_dict('list')
{'Results': [2.5, 2.0, 2.19, 1.243]}
```

Comment: I used the 1st option it works good. To get around the decimal displayed I added `astype(str)` but this does not work when the precision is 0.

Comment: @ShaneS it's a float value, so `round(0)` still produces a float value, so you'll have the `.0` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
df['new']=df['Results'].copy()
df=df.round({'new': 1})
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Although this does not take into account the decimal column which is the required precision.